# android shape xml shows different for API 19 and 21

Tags: android, shapes

i've got a shape xml like this:

```
drawable/contact_list_fastscroll_bubble.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="44dp"
        android:topRightRadius="44dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="44dp"/>
    <padding
        android:paddingLeft="22dp"
        android:paddingRight="22dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/app_color_green"/>
</shape>
```

this code is ported from AOSP: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d3383d5bfab296ba3adbc121ff8a7b542bde4afb/core/res/res/drawable/fastscroll_label_right_material.xml.

on api 21, it look like this, and is what i want for api 19.

[image: API 21]
but on api 19, it looks different, and is NOT what i want.

[image: API 19]
i wonder:

1. why it changed the shape, and
2. how to get the first image in api 19?

thanks!

---

edit:

i take screenshots on 2 emulators, both based on Nexus 6p with 2560x1440, only api level differs.

---

edit 2:

i'd like to explain how the shape drawable is measured.

i use this drawable as following:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@drawable/contact_list_fastscroll_bubble</item>
</style>
```

where `contact_list_fastscroll_bubble` is the xml posted above.

the attribute `android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight` sets the `fast scroller drawable` of the `ListView`. so it's the responsiblity of `ListView` to measure the drawable. developers don't need to set the size of the drawable.

Comment: How did you tested and confirmed this..?

Comment: it's ported from AOSP: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d3383d5bfab296ba3adbc121ff8a7b542bde4afb/core/res/res/drawable/fastscroll_label_right_material.xml, with tag of android-5.1.1_r37.

Comment: @gvsharma i make the screenshots on phones of api 19 and 21. what about that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like rounded corners count into padding before Lollipop. Create two variants of the drawable.

#### drawable/contact_list_fastscroll_bubble.xml

No extra padding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="44dp"
        android:topRightRadius="44dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="44dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/app_color_green"/>
</shape>
```

#### drawable-v21/contact_list_fastscroll_bubble.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="44dp"
        android:topRightRadius="44dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="44dp"/>
    <padding
        android:paddingLeft="22dp"
        android:paddingRight="22dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/app_color_green"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but this might be one reason. Your shape is rectangle and you're just making corners in round shape so this is reflecting arc based on your dp. In api 21 (high resolution device) dp is more so its look circular but in api 19 maybe you'e using less resolution device so its making rectangular.

Comment: how can you assume API 21 are having high resolution and API 19 are having low resolution? Can you  assert your answer?

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have 2 emulators both based on Nexus 6p with 2560x1440, only api level differs.

Comment: You're right @gvsharma. We can't assume but resolution might be one issue. But I don't know how is he testing.

Comment: @Mukesh i've editted my question, adding test environment.

Comment: Ok.. how can you assure that your length of the rectangle is 88 dp, coz you're giving coner as 44 and trying to get circular arc which should pass through half of the length of rectangle side. are you setting lengh dynamically in java?

Comment: @Mukesh as to measuring the drawable, i've editted my post. thanks.